# Shorted antenna DC-blocking capacitor value

Tags: rf, ground, gps

I have an antenna that contains a DC short to ground ( a [PIFA antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip_antenna#Other_types) at 1575 MHz in this case ). However, my device cannot tolerate a DC short to ground, so I need to include a blocking capacitor in series with the antenna.

How can I find the value of the DC blocking capacitor of a shorted-to-ground antenna?

Comment: An Inverted F Antenna is shorted to ground. The feed is thus shorted to ground too. Without a DC blocking mechanism, anything North of the feed would be shorted too. This DC-Blocking capacitor value is usually specified by the antenna manufacturer but I would like to learn the formula to deduce its value.

Comment: @Andyaka I've gotta say that I didn't find the question *that* cryptic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 1.5GHz the exact type of capacitor is important as well the the capacitance value.
Many types of capacitor will self resonate well below 1.5GHz. The capacitor does not act like a perfect capacitor, instead it acts like a capacitor with an inductor in series.

If your capacitor was perfect and your antenna impedance at 1.5GHz is entirely resistive then you would only need to consider the impedance of the capacitor and make it low enough that it has no effect on the rf.
A perfect 100uF capacitor would have an impedance of a tiny fraction of an ohm at 1.5GHz. In reality a 100uF electrolytic capacitor dosn't work at 1.5GHz due to inductance of the leads and the coiled plates.

You have to use a tiny surface mount capacitor for 1.5GHZ.

If you have a typically antenna system characteristic impedance of 50-75ohms
then making the capacitor impedance under 1ohm means it has no practical effect.
Maybe you want to try for 0.1ohm if you want to get the last 0.1dB of performance if you are designing expensive satellite equipment.

TO figure out the minimum capacitance value to get below 1 ohm at 1.5GHz you can use the 1/2.pi.F.C formula from any basic electronics textbook.
It works out that you need a capacitor of 100pF or larger.
The practical problem then becomes picking a capacitor that has low enough parasitic inductance and dielectric loss to actually work.

The behavior of common components at microwave frequencies is often not specified by the manufacturer. This is when you realise why RF is seen as a black art. You sometimes need to spend some time reading, looking at stuff other people have deigned and testing things in your lab full of RF gear to find out what works.

If you antenna impedance is significantly inductive or capacitive then you can make it more complicated by using the block cap as part of a matching circuit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you happen to know if "CX" is the usual abbreviation for the blocking capacitor ? ST seems to recommend Murata 220pF GRM1555C1H221JA01D at ~900Mhz (formula result = 0.83). Is picking a capacitor with common parameters but adjusted to ~1575Mhz a good option ? GRM1555C1H121JA01D (same serie) is 120pF wtih a formula result of 0.84 at 1575Mhz. Thank you !

Comment: Looking at the datasheets, around 1.6GHz the first one is about 0.4+3j, it acts like an inductor of about 3ohms.

looking at GRM1555C1H121JA01D datasheet at about 1.6GHz it' impedance is about 0.2+2j, it acts like an
inductor of about 2ohm impedance.

I think either will work, given the choice I'd probably pick the second one, maybe try two in parallel.
You will need some decent test gear to usefully measure the difference.
Practically if you made a device with a built in antenna and carefully compared both capacitors either
might win by a decibel depending on the actual antenna impedance.

Comment: You might wish to consider Murata's GJM line for high frequency capacitors.